# Query DB for column value that is in a given array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to query a table in my database for the rows in which both the columns home_team and away_team contain a value that is in an array. No such luck, however. My code is as follows.

```
$new_array = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($ncaa);$i++)
{
//  Since some of the values in this array contain apostrophes, escape each value 
$new_array[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($ncaa[$i]);   
}

$list = join(",", $new_array);
$query = "SELECT * 
     FROM ncaa_games
     WHERE game_date_int >= '".$limit."' 
     AND (home_team = '".mysql_real_escape_string($team)."' OR away_team = '".mysql_real_escape_string($team)."') 
     AND home_team IN (".$list.")
     AND away_team IN (".$list.")
     ORDER BY game_date_int ASC 
     LIMIT 1";

$next = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

I keep in getting an error message reading "ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''UTSA Roadrunners") AND away_team IN (Albany Great Danes,Binghamton Bear' at line 5"

I have a feeling that this could be something rather simple. But, it's still managing to elude me. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: is it possible that game_date_int is an int and you are trying to pass it a string?

Comment: What is this? `AND (home_team = '".mysql_real_escape_string($team)."' OR away_team = '".mysql_real_escape_string($team)."')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$list = join(",", $new_array);
```

Will not enclose the teams in quotes. I.e. you have:

```
away_team IN (Albany Great Danes,Binghamton Bears)
```

When this should be:

```
away_team IN ('Albany Great Danes','Binghamton Bears')
```

Try using:
    $list = join("','", $new_array);
and having:

```
 AND home_team IN ('".$list."')
 AND away_team IN ('".$list."')
```

(Make sure `$list` isn't empty).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had a feeling is was a simple syntax error. Something trivial.

Comment: @Lance No problem. A fresh set of eyes always helps :)